# bootstrap full page with div row 80% and 20%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I achieve with bootstrap that full page with div row 80% and 20%.

```
----------
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
----------
|        |
----------
```

Yes, i can achieve it with table but i want to know will it able to do with div row class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use modern browsers 'vh' measure to set a block size in % of viewport height, then use Bootstraps - container-fluid to get a 100% wide container to wrap the two 80 / 20 divs.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="eighty">
    80%
  </div>
  <div class="twenty">
    20%
  </div>
</div>
```

And style them:

```
.eighty {
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}

.twenty {
    height: 20vh;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/VASmt6damfbQCk2zcAg0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

With a basic bootstrap layout like this,

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="row eighty">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      First column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Second column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row twenty">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      First column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Second column
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can extend the row heights to percentages of the window height.

```
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.content {
  height:100%;
}

.eighty {
  height:80%;
}

.twenty {
  height:20%;
}
```

Note how the html, body and .content elements are all set to 100% of the window height.